# How to deploy Apache Beam to Dataflow using google cloud build?

Tags: deployment, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-build, cloudbuild.yaml

I have a pipeline written in java and its template is deployed on google cloud storage when running the Pipeline.

What I want is to generate a `Dockerfile` and `cloudbuild.yaml` file then I can deploy using `gcloud builds submit` I just want the template to be deployed using cloud build **(I want to deploy the template to cloud storage when the submit the image without running it)** to create a trigger later I don't want to implement the entire CI/CD cycle so how my yaml file should contain.

**Note:**  I'm passing the args using the `PipelineOptionsFactory`:

```
//configure options
        options.setRunner(DataflowRunner.class);
        options.setRegion("europe-west1");
        options.setTemplateLocation(TEMP_PATH + "/templates/log_v2");
        options.setTempLocation(TEMP_PATH + "/temp/batch");
        options.setStagingLocation(TEMP_PATH + "/temp/staging");
        options.setMaxNumWorkers(10);
```

Comment: You are using `Dataflow Flex Template` ?

Comment: No, I'm using the Classic template. @MazlumTosun

Comment: Could you try following this [document](https://medium.com/@zhongchen/dataflow-ci-cd-with-cloudbuild-1ad503c1c81) to deploy Dataflow using cloud build?

Comment: Hi @MohamedHaydar, Did the above document help you in resolving the issue?

Comment: Hi @PrajnaRaiT the documentation is out of my scope